# Where to start typesetting chess with TeX

Tags: chess

I noticed that there are already a few questions about typesetting chess but I have two very basic ones:

1. What are currently the "best" packages to typeset chess diagrams and game scores with comments?
2. Are any of these already included in TeXShop?

Comment: TeXShop is an editor, and therefore includes no packages at all. TeXShop is distributed with MacTeX, which is a TeX Live distribution (that includes many packages.)

Comment: @Alan Munn : thanks for precising the matter. I guess that the question becomes: is there any chess typesetting package already included in MacTeX ?

Comment: I can confirm now that the package skak is included in the MacTeX distribution: I tried to write a chess text after including \usepackage{skak} in the preamble and it worked!

Comment: Unless you install the BasicTeX version of MacTeX, there is very little that the full MacTeX distribution doesn't contain.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. In my opinion, the best place to *start* with typesetting chess diagrams would be the [`skak` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/skak). The package provides a means for typesetting a board, saving and restoring it and also print moves. It relies on the [`chessfss` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss) that provides the board pieces.

   The easiest way to setup a board is using the `\fenboard` command. It allows for specifying a regular 8x8 chess board using the well-established [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation). For example,

   ```
   \fenboard{r5k1/1b1p1ppp/p7/1p1Q4/2p1r3/PP4Pq/BBP2b1P/R4R1K w - - 0 20}
   ```

   produces

   [image: Chess board setup using FEN]

   There is also [`texmate`](http://ctan.org/texmate), although I am unfamiliar with its interface.
2. TeXShop is a [LaTeX IDE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) and is therefore actually independent from any of TeX/LaTeX's packages. You should check your distribution for this. Easiest would be to include a package and see whether your `.tex` source compiles. If not, install the package using the available package manager (TeX Live or MiKTeX on Windows, say).

Comment: This is a good answer. I would only add that if you're adding comments a la Chess Informant (languageless; i.e. symbolic) then `texmate` and `skak` seem about even to me. But if your comments are in words then `skak` seems a little bit better because of the `\wmove` and `\bmove` commands. I also add the package `chessboard` to mark squares. Depending on your how you intend to comment on the games, this package is worth looking into.

Comment: That <code>fenboard</code> command that you use there does not produce that output. It would be <code>\fenboard{r5k1/1b1p1ppp/p7/1p1Q4/4P3/PP4Pq/BBP2b1P/R4R1K w - - 0 20}</code> Just thought I would clear that up.

Comment: Actually it seems the picture does not quite correspond to the fenboard command in row 4.

Answer (score 12):

@Werner gave a rather comprehensive answer and I agree that `skak` is a prime choice. I'd just like to add that several extensions built to work with `skak` exist: [`skaknew`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/skaknew) (adds new chess fonts) or the extension [`xskak`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xskak):

> The main point of the package xskak is to save informations about a chess game for later use.

It's also worth mentioning the [`chessboard` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chessboard), which makes it easier to produce animated chessboards, but requires also the `animate` package.

Pick your weapon. :)

Comment: skaknew is not an extension of skak, it is only a font package (an extended type1 version of the original skak fonts). skak will use  this fonts anyway as chessfss sets them up as default.

Comment: Also chessboard doesn't produce animated boards. The animation is done with the `animate` package and could also be done e.g. only with `skak`. The combination of `xskak`/`chessboard` only makes it easier to loop through the board positions. The main purpose of chessboard is more flexibility regarding the look of the board (partial boards, decoration, boarder etc) and the filling with pieces.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks for the clarifications. I edited my answer to make it more accurate. These are your packages after all. :)